# Google Feed API with jQuery`s AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-feed-api

I'm trying to load a RSS feed using Google's Feed API which gives me a JSON string.
(documentation: https://developers.google.com/feed/).

However, I'm trying to use jQuery's AJAX instead of vanilla JavaScript XHR.
It is not working for some reason, which I can't identify why. 
Loading the URL in the browser works, however (get the link in the code below).

I have prepared a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gberger/fNwpD/

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?hl=ja&output=json-in-script&q=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.gawker.com%2Flifehacker%2Ffull&v=1.0&num=3',
        success: function(data){
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(this.url);
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
});
```

Comment: Would you please also show the working vanilla code? It should show the same error you get in the console with this code.

Comment: Your fiddle shows Same Origin Policy error.

Comment: Please use the [console in your browser](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) to easily debug code like this. If you ask for help, better include the error message as well.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I did, it didn't help.

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger There should have been an error message complaining about `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` stuff or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add `dataType: 'jsonp'` to your options object. Your code is not working because of the [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). JSONP is one way of dealing with this if the server supports it (Feed API does).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'xy',
    success: function () {},
    error: function () {},
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

[Your working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNwpD/3/)

Comment: Wow. One character fix. Haha. Thanks!

Comment: @GuilhermeBerger But that character changes a lot :).